# Sympy precision using rationals

Tags: sympy

In sympy using large rationals, ie

```
xa2=2869041017039531/549755813888

xtotatives=5221

print(Rational(2869041017039531/549755813888)*5221)
```

For a larger set of similar fractions I am getting unexpected output when I check the number of distinct fractions.  Is there a way to increase the precision in sympy for rationals using simple code like this?

Edit1:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from sympy import Symbol, Rational, fraction
#from decimal import *

#getcontext().prec = 10000 #digits of precision for decimal


A060753=[1, 2, 3, 15, 35, 77, 1001]
A038110=[1, 1, 1, 4, 8, 16, 192]

totatives=[]

#primesList=[2,3,5,7]
#primesList=[2,3,5,7,11]
primesList=[2,3,5,7,11,13]

primeProduct=math.prod(primesList)
nToUse=len(primesList)

valuesToCheck=range(1,primeProduct)
for n in valuesToCheck:
    if math.gcd(n, primeProduct)==1 and n<primeProduct:
        totatives.append(n)

print(len(totatives))

correctOutput=[]
incorrectOutput=[]
a2=[]

k=0
totativeCount=len(totatives)
while k<totativeCount:
    #if k%round(totativeCount/50)==1:
        #print(f"loop {k+1} of {totativeCount}")
    
    a2.append(A060753[nToUse]/A038110[nToUse]*(k+1))

    correctOutput.append(A060753[nToUse]*(k+1)-A038110[nToUse]*totatives[k])
        
    incorrectOutput.append((Rational(a2[k])-Rational(totatives[k]))*A038110[nToUse])

    k+=1


print(f"count of distinct correct: {len(np.unique(correctOutput))}")
print(f"sum(correctOutput): {sum(correctOutput)}")

print(f"count of distinct incorrect: {len(np.unique(incorrectOutput))}")
print(f"sum(incorrectOutput): {float(sum(incorrectOutput))}")
```

Output:

```
count of distinct correct: 2422
sum(correctOutput): 2882880
count of distinct incorrect: 3408
sum(incorrectOutput): 2882880.000000864
```

Cheers,
Jamie

Comment: Could you show a minimal example of this happening? It is possible that some of your large rationals are indeed equal and therefore only one unique fraction is included in the set. Consider `1/2 = x/2x` where `x=9999999999999999999999999999999`.

Comment: This question is very unclear and makes no sense so I can't answer it but I can say that you should use `Rational(1, 3)` rather than `Rational(1/3)`.

Comment: Thanks, I added an example that I think shows the precision error I am trying to fix.

Comment: An annoying [gotcha](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#two-final-notes-and) is that Python converts divisions between integers to floats before sympy can get its hand on them.  Floats are imprecise by definition. You can avoid this, e.g. by writing `A060753[nToUse]/S(A038110[nToUse])*(k+1)` (using `from sympy import S`).

Comment: Further, note that you really should avoid `numpy` and `math` while working with sympy. These libraries calculate with floats, while sympy tries to keep everything with exact symbolical values. E.g. `math.gcd`, `math.prod` and `np.unique` aren't appropriate inside sympy code.  You could use sympy functions such as `primerange` and `primorial` [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.generate.primorial), or just write loops to multiply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy doesn't use a global precision like `decimal`. Every SymPy `Float` object stores its own precision (defaulting to 15 digits).

If you want to use rational numbers, your best bet is to just avoid floats entirely. This can be done by ensuring your integers are SymPy integers. This can be done by calling sympify() on values that start out as Python integers, like

```
A060753 = sympify([1, 2, 3, 15, 35, 77, 1001])
A038110 = sympify([1, 1, 1, 4, 8, 16, 192])
```

And also using `sympy.prod` and `sympy.gcd` instead of `math.prod` and `math.gcd`. This avoids the gotcha where dividing two Python `int` objects produces a float, which loses information about the exact rational number it represents.

If you do this, the results will be rational numbers. You can then convert these to floats with as many digits as you want with `number.evalf()`